# Customer Portal without licenses

Tags: customer-portal

Is it possible to build a custom customer portal that access Salesforce data without a user? For example: the portal would be a web app written form scratch, and it would communicate with Salesforce through APIs.

Can this be done without registered users on the org, while keeping a good authentication for the API?

What I mean by this is that the web app would need to authenticate with Salesforce when making requests, but I would like to do this without using Salesforce user credentials.

I know that this could be done with the web app using credentials/tokens that can be analyzed at the beginning of the API request handling with Apex, but I'm not sure if this is secure enough.

If there is another way of doing this, I would like to know.

The context is that I want to create a portal for specific customers, so they would be able to see/track orders, for example. I'm not sure of how many users from these customer companies would use the app (hence the need for not using Salesforce licenses, because they are too expensive for this situation).

Also, Salesforce has a limit of 100 communities per org, so if I get more than 100 customers that use this service, Salesforce would not be able to provide what I need.

At the end I need an individual customer portal, since each customer has different needs.

Comment: So, you need to have at least one user so that you can at the very least have a guest user.  As far as your connection to an external, non salesforce app, I couldn't say for sure.  Can you elaborate on what you are stating in regards to the limit of 100 communities? You can have thousands of users under a single community.

Comment: What I meant is that the ratio of community per customer would be 1:1, but the business isn't limited to 100 customers like the communities. Each community would be a customized experience for the specific customer.

Comment: You can achieve this by creating dynamic fields on a custom object that is related to the contact.  Have URL to banner image, style class options they can  pick from, available views based off of criteria, etc.  You don't need a new community per customer.

Comment: Do you have an example? How would custom functionallity be controlled then? Profile-based?

Comment: Don't forget about API limits. More users mean more API calls.

Comment: Although that is true, for the kind of service I'm thinking I wouldn't need many calls. Batch services that run on a hourly basis would be enough to feed the information to the web app. I don't think API Limits are an issue, but authentication with the platform is, since the web app wouldn't be a Salesforce user.

Comment: Assuming you are ok with guest user view limits, you can create a simple webapp on heroku and have it store customers credentials and once user successfully logged in, redirect them to your site and this should work I guess.

Comment: In Communities it is possible to have page variations based on Profile or Location of the customer using standard functionality across the entire community. Salesforce refer to this as Audience Targeting https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_manage.htm&type=0

Answer (score 1):

This example will be done with Lightning Attributes, but you could use VF page with custom controller just as easy.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<ObjectName__c> getInfo(){

List<User> usr = [SELECT Id, ContactID FROM User WHERE Id = : UserInfo.getUserId()];
List<Contact> cont =  [SELECT Id, LookupFieldToObject__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = : usr.get(0).ContactID limit 1];

    return [SELECT Id, imgURL__c, bannerClass__c
        FROM ObjectName__c
        WHERE Id = : cont.get(0).LookupFieldToObject__c
        Limit 1
        ];
}
```

The following would be your cmp:

```
<div class="{!v.bannerClass}" style="{!'background-image:' + v.bannerImage}">
    <h4>Thank you for returning <br></br>
    {!v.contactName}</h4>
</div>

<div style="{!'display: ' + v.displayType}">
    Information to show or not show, that is the question.
</div>
```

I used some of this for another explanation [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180349/apex-value-as-default-on-component-attribute/180354#180354)

The point is, that you don't need a new community for each user, because this small example shows how you can change the look and feel of everything, per user.

Comment: I often use a formula on such objects that output text like: "darkClass", "lightClass", "none", "block", that can then be used in the html style or class, so that it becomes more dynamic... I added the "none" and "block" to my example, in the portion for display, so that you can dynamically hide or show divs...

Comment: Obviously, you would have a "darkClass" and a "lightClass" in your CSS, so that when it did dynamically change, the style you want would be reflected.  A picklist that the user can select is another option so that they can pick what CSS they want...